# doctrine : onDelete="CASCADE" not working correctly?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entity with a manyToMany relationship : `Teacher` and `Subject`.

### Can you tell me why i've got empty row ? I want to delete these `Subject` with no `Teacher` attached.

### Edit

I added `cascade={"remove", "persist"},` on `Teacher` (see my entities below), but now, if i have this :

```
|Subject name|Teacher(s)|
 ------------------------
|Maths       | John, Bob, Bill|
|Science     | John     |
|Sport       | Doe      |
|Foo         | Bar      |
|Babar       | John     |

Teacher(s) |
------------
| John     |
| Doe      |
| Bar      |
| ...      |
```

i get that when i delete `John` :

```
|Subject name|Teacher(s)|
 ------------------------  Not good
|                       | <-- entire row deleted
|Science     | John     |
|Sport       | Doe      |
|Foo         | Bar      |
|            |          | <-- here too

Teacher(s) |
------------
| John     |
| Doe      |
| Bar      |
| ...      |
```

instead of this :

```
|Subject name|Teacher(s)|
 ------------------------  Good
|Maths       | Bob, Bill|  <-- only jhon deleted
|Science     | John     |
|Sport       | Doe      |
|Foo         | Bar      |
|            |          | <-- entire row deleted

Teacher(s) |
------------
| Doe      |
| Bar      |
| ...      |
```

I want to delete the `Subject` row only if there is not `Teacher` attached

Here my entities

`Teacher` :

```
class Teacher
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string",     length=255)
 */
private $firstname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $lastname;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Subject", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, mappedBy="teachers"))
 */
private $subjects;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set firstname
 *
 * @param string $firstname
 *
 * @return Teacher
 */
public function setFirstname($firstname)
{
    $this->firstname = $firstname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get firstname
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->firstname;
}

/**
 * Set lastname
 *
 * @param string $lastname
 *
 * @return Teacher
 */
public function setLastname($lastname)
{
    $this->lastname = $lastname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastname
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->lastname;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->subjects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add subject
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject
 *
 * @return Teacher
 */
public function addSubject(\AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject)
{
    $this->subjects[] = $subject;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove subject
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject
 */
public function removeSubject(\AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject)
{
    $this->subjects->removeElement($subject);
}

/**
 * Get subjects
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getSubjects()
{
    return $this->subjects;
}
}
```

`Subject` :

```
class Subject
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Teacher", inversedBy="subjects"))
 */
private $teachers;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=7, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
public $color;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->teachers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get teachers
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTeachers()
{
    return $this->teachers;
}

/**
 * Add teacher
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function addTeacher(\AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher)
{
    $this->teachers[] = $teacher;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove teacher
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher
 */
public function removeTeacher(\AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher)
{
    $this->teachers->removeElement($teacher);
}

/**
 * Set color
 *
 * @param string $color
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function setColor($color)
{
    $this->color = $color;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get color
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getColor()
{
    return $this->color;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If want a many-to-many relationship, you need a linkage table. You can specify it in annotation, at entity **Teacher**

```
/**
 * Owning Side
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Subject", inversedBy="teachers", cascade={"remove"})
 * @JoinTable(name="teacher_subject",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="teacher_id",
 *          referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="subject_id",
 *      referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 *   )
*/
private $subjects;
```

and at entity **Subject** (reverse side)

```
/**
  * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teacher", mappedBy="subjects")
*/
private $teachers;
```

Drop the **@ORM\JoinColumn** from $id property at **Teacher** and

run `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i already have a linkage table (generated by doctrine with manyToMany relation) named `subject_teacher`. I tried you solution but i've got the same problem : orphan Subjects when i delete the Teacher.
I used `cascade={"remove", "persist"}` on `Teacher` and now when i delete a teacher, it cascade to the `Subject`. But when a `Subject` got multiple `Teacher`, it delete all the row (Subject + Teacher ). I m going to edit my post

Comment: try to add onDelete="CASCADE" on the Entity side of relationship. I just edited the answer to accomplish that. But in this case I guess the subject row is going to be deleted as well. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: Yes i already tried to add onDelete="CASCADE"  on `referencedColumnName="id"`, it didn't work like i want. I want to delete the Subject row only if there is no Teacher attached to it. Thanks you

Comment: I've got! But... it's not possible to achieve this through annotation/relationship mapping. You might you something like a lifecycle callback. For example, when you delete a Teacher, the callback checks if there'are still some teacher assigned to the subject. If not the subject is deleted.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-postremove

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll definitly checkout for these callbacks.